# Building package with Rcpp, generated .h file missing header

Tags: r, rcpp

I am currently building a package in RStudio that uses Rcpp. I have defined the following .cpp file, which works with `Rcpp::sourceCpp`.

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::interfaces(r, cpp)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::unordered_set<int> traverse_cor(NumericMatrix x, float maxcor) {
  std::unordered_set<int> elements;
  int ncol = x.ncol();
  for(int i = 0; i < ncol; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < ncol; j++) {
      if(i < j) {
        if(x(i, j) > maxcor && x(i, j) < 1){
          elements.insert(i + 1); 
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return elements;
}
```

I am following the directions from [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html) and [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf). Next I call `Rcpp::compileAttributes()`. This produces the following files:

- src/RcppExports.cpp
- R/RcppExports.R
- inst/include/mypackage.h
- inst/include/mypackage_RcppExports.h

The generated mypackage_RcppExports.h file looks as follows:

```
// This file was generated by Rcpp::compileAttributes
// Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

#ifndef __gwassim_RcppExports_h__
#define __gwassim_RcppExports_h__

#include <Rcpp.h>

namespace gwassim {

    using namespace Rcpp;

    namespace {
        void validateSignature(const char* sig) {
            Rcpp::Function require = Rcpp::Environment::base_env()["require"];
            require("gwassim", Rcpp::Named("quietly") = true);
            typedef int(*Ptr_validate)(const char*);
            static Ptr_validate p_validate = (Ptr_validate)
                R_GetCCallable("gwassim", "gwassim_RcppExport_validate");
            if (!p_validate(sig)) {
                throw Rcpp::function_not_exported(
                    "C++ function with signature '" + std::string(sig) + "' not found in gwassim");
            }
        }
    }

    inline std::unordered_set<int> traverse_cor(NumericMatrix x, float maxcor) {
        typedef SEXP(*Ptr_traverse_cor)(SEXP,SEXP);
        static Ptr_traverse_cor p_traverse_cor = NULL;
        if (p_traverse_cor == NULL) {
            validateSignature("std::unordered_set<int>(*traverse_cor)(NumericMatrix,float)");
            p_traverse_cor = (Ptr_traverse_cor)R_GetCCallable("gwassim", "gwassim_traverse_cor");
        }
        RObject __result;
        {
            RNGScope __rngScope;
            __result = p_traverse_cor(Rcpp::wrap(x), Rcpp::wrap(maxcor));
        }
        if (__result.inherits("interrupted-error"))
            throw Rcpp::internal::InterruptedException();
        if (__result.inherits("try-error"))
            throw Rcpp::exception(as<std::string>(__result).c_str());
        return Rcpp::as<std::unordered_set<int> >(__result);
    }

}

#endif // __gwassim_RcppExports_h__
```

After attempting to build and reload the package, I receive the following errors (1):

> ../inst/include/gwassim_RcppExports.h:27:12: error: 'unordered_set' in
>   namespace 'std' does not name a type

And (2)

> RcppExports.cpp:12:1: error: 'unordered_set' in namespace 'std' does
>   not name a type

I have limited C++ experience, but my sense is that these errors occur due to `#include <unordered_set>` being omitted. How do I get these automatically generated files to have the correct headers?

My sessionInfo is the following:

```
Session info ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (0.99.235)          
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/New_York            

Packages --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package    * version    date       source                          
 devtools     1.7.0.9000 2015-02-11 Github (hadley/devtools@9415a8a)
 digest     * 0.6.4      2013-12-03 CRAN (R 3.1.0)                  
 memoise    * 0.2.1      2014-04-22 CRAN (R 3.1.0)                  
 mvtnorm      1.0-2      2014-12-18 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                  
 Rcpp         0.11.4     2015-01-24 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                  
 roxygen2   * 4.1.0      2014-12-13 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                  
 rstudioapi * 0.2        2014-12-31 CRAN (R 3.1.2)                  
 stringr    * 0.6.2      2012-12-06 CRAN (R 3.0.0)
```

And my version of g++ is 4.6.3, as included in the RTools package for Windows. I have enabled C++11 features with the following:
`Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-std=c++0x")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a finicky one. I think you want Section 3.5.2 of the [Rcpp Attributes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) vignette and this trick:

> The `Package.h` file does nothing other than include the
>   `Package_RcppExports.h` header. This is done so that package
>   authors can replace the `Package.h` header with a custom one
>   and still be able to include the automatically generated exports
>   (details on doing this are provided in the next section).

In passing, I think I also convinced you to create a package rather than to rely just on `sourceCpp()` :)

*Edit:* Doh!! I overlooked the part that

```
std::unordered_set<int> traverse_cor(NumericMatrix x, float maxcor)
```

is probably *not* an automatically wrappable function.  You may need to convert your set into a vector (or list or ...) to get one of the types that matches naturally into R.

Comment: OK, I tried the trick. I did the following: 1) edit the Package.h header to have `#include <unordered_set>` and deleted the token at the top and 2) attempted to build and reload the package. It seems that gets rid of the error with RcppExports.cpp, but I still get `../inst/include/gwassim_RcppExports.h:27:12: error: 'unordered_set' in namespace 'std' does not name a type`

Comment: Looks like I needed to change the order of the headers in the Package.h file. After doing so, I now receive a different error, with the original one gone: `include/Rcpp/internal/Exporter.h:31:31: error: invalid conversion from 'SEXP' to 'long long unsigned int' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: For that the simplest fix is to turn on C++11 support in the package.

Comment: I believe I am doing just that with `Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-std=c++0x")`, which I run prior to attempting to build the package.

Comment: Just to be plain, I'd add `CXX_STD = CXX11` in `src/Makevars`.

Comment: My src/Makevars file now looks like this: `PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include
PKG_CXXFLAGS = "-std=c++0x"
CXX_STD = CXX11
`, and I still receive the invalid conversion error

Comment: Are those three lines?  Anyway, I (ahem!!) overlooked a little detail. See my edit.

Comment: Those are three lines. Anyway, your edit worked. I converted the set to a vector and things work now. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know it works. If you have `CXX_STD=...` you do not need `PKG_CXXFLAGS` by the way.

Comment: I can build this package on Windows, but apparently it fails on any other platform. A lot of errors are produced, but start with `

`RcppExports.o:RcppExports.cpp:(.text.startup+0xb): undefined reference to __gxx_personality_sj0'` . Pretty sure I am using the same g++ on both platforms. This is on Ubuntu 14.10 with the same version of R and Rcpp.

Comment: Can you provide a complete tarball (or github repo)?  This should be easy to fix.  Alternatively:  start with a _clean_ new package from `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`, then import you code piece by piece.

Comment: 1) The repo has too many external dependencies I do not have; I don't have time for this: it is clearly *not* a minimally reproducible example.  2)  You have _object_ code in the repo; don't do that.  3) Restart from a plain package created via `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`; add your code step by step.

Comment: No bother, but keep _minimal examples_ in mind. Even if you don't submit them to someone it may make it clearer to _you_ what is at fault.  Enjoy Rcpp :)